# Find transformation matrix between 2 cameras

Tags: matlab, kinect, transformation, camera-calibration, projective-geometry

I'm trying to find the projective transformation between 2 cameras (Kinect RGB and IR) in Matlab, I had read several answers but all of them use OpenCV, by this moment I can find chessboard points in the 2 images (`imageRGBPoints`, `imageIRPoints`), and overlapping both images i get the following:

[image]

It's obvious that both cameras have different points of view.  After searching I had found this:

```
tform = fitgeotrans(imageRGBPoints ,imageIRPoints,'Projective');
Color_Transformed = imwarp(color, tform);
```

I get the first image with double size and small rotation.  Finally I have tried [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/sparse-3-d-reconstruction-from-multiple-views.html) tutorial from Mathworks, using SURF features but I don't understand where is the Matrix transformation, how can I fit both images?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got with a X-Box Kinect.

After scaling both images to 640x480,

ax = 9.1008894 + 0.924429*i

ay = 40.0500822 + 0.92345789*j

Where (i,j) are the coordinates of the pixel in the IR image (640x480) and ax, ay are the coordinates of the CORRESPONDING pixel in RGB.

Hope that helps.